# AngualrJS filter records that being with

Tags: angularjs, regex, filter, angularjs-scope

I have a field in my AngularJS scope called rid

This is always a 4 letter code such as 1A22 or 4D23 (number, letter, number, number)

I want to filter out (i.e not show) any that meet certain conditions

- begin with a 2K
- begin with a 5
- begin with 1C

Now I know I can build individual filters onto my ng-repeat (service in services), but i think the way forward is a nice custom filter where I can feed in an array of conditions that i want to filter out. I suspect a string of regex conditions is the answer

```
/^2k|5|1C*/
```

Can anyone advise the best way to approach this custom filter? Thanks

EDIT : This was my solution, regex from the accepted answer and the following filter

```
myApp.filter('regex', function() {
    return function(input, field, regex) {
        var patt = new RegExp(regex);
        var out = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(!patt.test(input[i][field]))
                out.push(input[i]);
        }
        return out;
    };
});
```

then I just use this in my ng-repeat

```
regex:'rid':'^(?:2K|5|1C)[A-Z0-9]+$'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not so far. This regex will match any text starting with `2K`, `5` or `1C`:

```
^(?:2K|5|1C)[A-Z0-9]+$
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/QIM8vp/2)

If you want to make sure the length is 4, you can use this one:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{4}$)(?:2K|5|1C)[A-Z0-9]+$
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/QIM8vp/3)